# Django-haystack can not filter by datetime

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

Version:
django-haystack (2.6.1)
Django (1.11.4)

I am trying to creating a search form, following by the tourial:
After filtering the start date, the sqs become empty.
What's wrong?

forms.py:

```
class DateRangeSearchForm(SearchForm):
    start_date = forms.DateTimeField(required=False)
    end_date = forms.DateTimeField(required=False)


    def search(self):
        sqs = super(DateRangeSearchForm, self).search()
        print (sqs[0].object.publish_date) #2017-10-23 02:10:40.673000+00:00
        print (self.cleaned_data['start_date']) #2017-10-17 00:00:00+08:00
        print (self.cleaned_data['start_date']<sqs[0].object.publish_date) #true
        print (len(sqs)) #19

        if not self.is_valid():
            print("no query found/n")
            return self.no_query_found()

        if self.cleaned_data['start_date']:
            sqs = sqs.filter(publish_date__gte=self.cleaned_data['start_date'])
            print(len(sqs))#0

        return sqs
```

views.py:

```
from .forms import DateRangeSearchForm
from .models import Article

class postManageSearchView(SearchView):
    template_name='backendSys/post_manageSearch.html'
    form_class = DateRangeSearchForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(postManageSearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        admin = self.request.user.profile.admin.get(admin__user__pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        permission = admin.permission.filter()
        articles = Article.objects.filter()
        context['permission'] = permission
        context['articles'] = articles
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [SearchOuerySet](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/searchqueryset_api.html) in `forms.py`

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
    class DateRangeSearchForm(SearchForm):
        start_date = forms.DateTimeField(required=False)
        end_date = forms.DateTimeField(required=False)


        def search(self):
            sqs = super(DateRangeSearchForm, self).search()
            print (sqs[0].object.publish_date) 
            print (self.cleaned_data['start_date'])
            print (self.cleaned_data['start_date']<sqs[0].object.publish_date)
            print (len(sqs)) 

            if not self.is_valid():
                print("no query found/n")
                return self.no_query_found()

            if self.cleaned_data['start_date']:
                sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(publish_date__gte=self.cleaned_data['start_date'])
                print(len(sqs))
            return sqs
```

add `get_queryset()` in `views.py`

```
class postManageSearchView(SearchView):
    template_name='backendSys/post_manageSearch.html'
    form_class = DateRangeSearchForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(postManageSearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        admin = self.request.user.profile.admin.get(admin__user__pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        permission = admin.permission.filter()
        articles = Article.objects.filter()
        context['permission'] = permission
        context['articles'] = articles
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(postManageSearchView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.all
```

Comment: I had tried it. Nothing change. Sqs still empty after filtering.

Comment: Provide your `views.py`

Comment: Added it in the question.

Comment: Try to pass queryset in your `views.py`

Comment: Still empty. QAQ